# How to bypass this masking element '9'?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have here a MaskedTextBox that has a custom maksed of `+639000000000` but the it will show only `+63__________` and what I really want is `+639_________`. I know that char `9` is a masking element [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=windowsdesktop-6.0),

> Question: How to bypass this masking element '9'?

Comment: Try escaping the character so that it appears as a literal as per the documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: oh, thanks, I missed to read the escaping \ character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `+63\9000000000`
as shown in : [MaskedTextBox.Mask Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). The `\` can escape the masking element `9`.